# determinant multiplication of multiple matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that $\det(A\cdot B)=\det(A)\cdot \det(B)$ but does it still hold true for $n>2$ matrices?

for example: $\det(A\cdot B \cdot C)=\det(A)\cdot \det(B) \cdot \det(C)$:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Seeing this is pretty easy:

$\det(A \cdot B \cdot C) = \det((A \cdot B) \cdot C) = \det(A \cdot B) \cdot \det(C) = \det(A) \cdot \det(B) \cdot \det(C)$.

Answer (score 3):

This statement is true for every $n\ge2$. You can use the induction to prove it. The step $n=2$ is the Binet theorem, for $n>2$ you use this theorem $n-1$ times and you find the result.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly. Let $D= BC$. Then $\det(D) = \det(B)\det(C)$ and $\det(ABC) = \det(AD) = \det(A)\det(D) = \det(A)\det(B)\det(C)$.